# Matplotlib.plot_date automatically adds in dates no on my data series, why and how to avoid?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm new to python/matplotlib, while I'm experimenting I encourage this strange behavior that the produced chart always shows those points(dates) that ain't exist on my series. I tried to search from the doc and web but couldn't find much clue.  Here's how I produced the chart:

`import pymysql
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

serial_no = '163406'
start_date = '2020-06-28'

mysql = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",port=3306,user="dbuser",passwd="psword",db="expdb")
cursor = mysql.cursor()

sql = "select r.t_date ,r.acc_av from expdb.records r \
        where r.sn = '"+serial_no+"'and r.t_date >= '"+start_date+"' order by r.t_date ASC"

data= pd.read_sql(sql, mysql, parse_dates=['t_date'])
data = data.set_index('t_date')

plt.plot_date(fdata.index,data[['acc_av']],linestyle=':', marker='.', label='acc av')

plt.show()`

The datatype of datatype:

```
fund_df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 32 entries, 2020-11-30 to 2021-01-13
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   acc_av  32 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 1.5 KB
```

A few sample data:

```
data.head(10)
            acc_av
t_date  
2020-11-30  7.0706
2020-12-01  7.2280
2020-12-02  7.2234
2020-12-03  7.2360
2020-12-04  7.2889
2020-12-07  7.2660
2020-12-08  7.2721
2020-12-09  7.1850
2020-12-10  7.1953
2020-12-11  7.1542
```

There are few days certainly not in the series, ie 2020-12-05, 2020-12-06.

From the chart it produced, even the markers of these nonexistent dates, the timeframe appears still exists on the chart, that showing longer interval space from 12-04 to 12-07, for instance, it's the same regardless I used plt.plot() or plt.plot_date().
Is there a way to avoid matplotlib automatically put in these nonexistent date back into the chart ?

The produced chart [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taNA9.png)

The chart in different clearer line/marker style (echo on Ankur's comment below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGJkZ.png)

Comment: The dotted line may be removed by simply omitting `linestyle=':'` from the call to `plt.plot_date`. Would that help?

Comment: Thanks for quick respond.  Unfortunately it didn't work.  I changed different linestyle and marker,  it's the same.  Those missing days auto slip in without a marker, just an empty place holder :(